# Why is my data binding in .NET with WinUi3 not working?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, winui-3

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window
    x:Class="Prüfstand_Gallerie.MainWindow"
    xmlns=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation
    xmlns:x=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml
    xmlns:local="using:Prüfstand_Gallerie"
    xmlns:d=http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008
    xmlns:mc=http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006 xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
 
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.FirstName}"></TextBlock>
        <Button Content="Change Name" Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ChangeNameCommand}"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace Prüfstand_Gallerie
{
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
 
        }
 
        public MainWindowViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();
 
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
namespace Prüfstand_Gallerie.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
 
        [ObservableProperty]
        public string firstName = "Jack";
 
        [RelayCommand]
        public void ChangeName()
        {
            FirstName = "Tjark";
        }
 
        [RelayCommand]
        private void SelectItem(object param)
        {
 
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to implement the mvvm pattern with winUi3, but the property FirstName is not updating when the button is clicked, though the command is fired and the value changes as I can see while debugging. It does not change in the ui. Where is the problem?

Comment: Tested @AndrewKeepCoding 's answer, which works fine. As linked document said, *the binding object can optionally be configured to observe changes in the value of the data source property and refresh itself based on those changes (Mode="OneWay"). It can also optionally be configured to push changes in its own value back to the source property (Mode="TwoWay")*.

Answer (score 2):

`x:Bind` is `OneTime` by [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension#:%7E:text=%7Bx%3ABind%7D%20has,of%20the%20binding.). You need to explicitly set it to `OneWay`.

```xml
 <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.FirstName, Mode=OneWay}" />
```